# What is the gas distribution in galaxies?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, dark-matter, galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve

I'm fitting a number of galaxy rotation curves, and I need the density distributions of stars, gas, and DM. I know that the baryonic disk densities fall off exponentially (the characteristic radii can be found in the HyperLeda database), but I was also curious about the gas contribution: what function is it given by, and where one can find data on it?

Thank you in advance!